# How to close Jpanel window?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

What I am trying to do is to run a simulation using Java graphics and I am looping a bunch of jpanels. Once a condition is met in the simulation, I would like that specific jpanel to close. However, I am not sure how to do that. Currently I have tried using System.exit(0) but I want the other jpanels to continue running. Below is my code for the Pong class and the condition I am using. The condition is located in the board class and I also have a ball class and wall class.(Also this question is not about the game Pong I am using some old code to run the simulation)

```
 package Pong2;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.util.*;
        public class Pong2 extends JFrame {
            static int a;
            static int b;
            public  Pong2(int a,int b)
            {
                this.a=a;
                this.b=b;
                add(new Board2(a,b));
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setSize(1000, 1000);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                setVisible(true);
                setResizable(false);
            }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
               int[] primes=new int[]{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
             for (int i = 0; i <primes.length ; i++) {
                   for (int j = i+1; j <primes.length ; j++) {
                        Pong2 e=new Pong2(primes[i]*100,primes[j]*100);
                   }
             }
            }
        }
```

Board class

```
 if(ball.intersects(0,0,5,5)){
                    ball.stop();
                    System.out.println("Top left"+a/100+" "+b/100);
                    setVisible(false);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
```

Comment: The best way to close/dispose a JPanel is to first hide it, then remove it from the parent window, or if you are using a JFrame you would use dispose();. For example `yourJPanel.setVisible(false); parentContainer.remove(yourJPanel);` or for a jFrame `yourJFrame.dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close the JPanel and only the JPanel, do

```
yourFrame.remove(yourPanel);
```

If you want to remove the entire frame with it, do

```
yourFrame.dispose();
```